# AS3 variable, access throughout app?

Tags: actionscript-3

In AS3, is there a way to declare a variable in my base class and be able to access it in all other classes in the program?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use 'global' variables in AS3, you declare them `static`

```
public static var myGlobal:Object;
```

Whatever class that is declared in, you can then on access it by

```
ClassName.myglobal
```